How to extend container to cover entire/full screen in Flutterflow
I am trying to cover entire screen with a container (since I want to have a background image)
But there is an empty border at top for app flow and bottom for nav flow.
I've done the following.

Turned off App Flow
Turned off Nav Flow
Made the container have infinite height & width



I figured it out, heres how you do it.
Select the page, and inside the properties, turn of Safe Area. And thats it.

And this is how it looks now.

